# Isn't SQL Server Compact self sustained?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I have all the correct nuget packages, I have followed all guides found when googling on my error

> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: Unable to load the native
>   components of SQL Server Compact corresponding to the ADO.NET provider
>   of version 8876. Install the correct version of SQL Server Compact.
>   Refer to KB article 974247 for more details..

The test project that uses SQL Server Compact runs on my machine, but on the TeamCity build agent it fails with above exception.

This is my nuget config for test project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="CommonServiceLocator" version="1.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.7.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.7.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.7.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact" version="4.0.8876.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.UnitTestFramework.Extensions" version="1.0.0.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.7.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Unity" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
</packages>
```

The `app.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="buildtest" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" connectionString="data source=unittest.sdf" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.7.0.0" newVersion="5.7.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.7.0.0" newVersion="5.7.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.7.0.0" newVersion="5.7.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.2.0.0" newVersion="6.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
  </startup>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

I have done a binary compare using Beyond Compare on the output folder on my local machine and on the agent, they are identical

Update:
Checked the GAC on the build agent, none of below files are located there

- EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact.dll
- System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll

Comment: Did you check if another build version of SQLCE 4.0 is installed in GAC on the build server?

Comment: Hmm, its a clean install of Windows, but will check

Comment: Should I install this on the build machine? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876

Comment: Nope, that is not 4.0 SP1, that is 4.0 - but you can install 4.0 SP1...